# Multipage webforms in ASP.NET with the same url address

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, webforms

I making app when you can upload generally some files. So in upload action I wanna have 3 steps for uploading certain file. But If i will code it on 3 sites it wont be the same url. I just want to change content of eg. first page in first step and then if user add correct information I wanna change in that url content of that page. Can you helpme ? some ideas or example of code. 
Alexander Dračka

Comment: You might want look at MultiView control

Comment: if you wanna use some builtin functionality of asp.net look into wizard view,panels and multiview.

Comment: http://www.asp.net/single-page-application This is worth looking at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use panel for the same.
Put your 3 codes in 3 panel and As per your requirement you can show and hide the panel.

Comment: Do you mean simple panel control in asp.net?Is it good idea? but thanks i will try it

Comment: Well, you migth run into troubles, if you will need to add another step later

Comment: as per your question,panel is a simplest way. Give a try and let me know,My suggestion will help you or not.

Comment: Well finally i decide try the Multiview and im satisfied:) Thanks a lot later I wanna try wizard cause its pretty nice

Answer (score 0):

What about `Wizard` control? it has several views and you can navigate each of them